# I get an error [<class 'decimal.ConversionSyntax'>] in my cart, how do I fix this?

Tags: django

When adding an item to the cart, an error occurs InvalidOperation at /cart/
[<class 'decimal.ConversionSyntax'>].

My code:

cart..py ...............................

```
from decimal import Decimal
from django.conf import settings
from TeaYardApp.models import Products


class Cart(object):

    def __init__(self, request):
        self.session = request.session
        cart = self.session.get(settings.CART_SESSION_ID)
        if not cart:
            cart = self.session[settings.CART_SESSION_ID] = {}
        self.cart = cart

    def __iter__(self):
        product_ids = self.cart.keys()
        # получаем товары и добавляем их в корзину
        product = Products.objects.filter(id__in=product_ids)

        cart = self.cart.copy()
        for product in product:
            cart[str(product.id)]['product'] = product

        for item in cart.values():
            item['price'] = Decimal(item['price'])
            item['total_price'] = item['price'] * item['quantity']
            yield item

    def __len__(self):
        return sum(item['quantity'] for item in self.cart.values())

    def add(self, product, quantity=1, update_quantity=False):
        product_id = str(product.id)
        if product_id not in self.cart:
            self.cart[product_id] = {'quantity': 0,
                                     'price': str(product.price)}
        if update_quantity:
            self.cart[product_id]['quantity'] = quantity
        else:
            self.cart[product_id]['quantity'] += quantity
        self.save()

    def save(self):
        self.session.modified = True

    def remove(self, product):
        product_id = str(product.id)
        if product_id in self.cart:
            del self.cart[product_id]
            self.save()

    def get_total_price(self):
        return sum(Decimal(item['price']) * item['quantity'] for item in self.cart.values())

    def clear(self):
        del self.session[settings.CART_SESSION_ID]
        self.save()
```

Form for adding goods to the cart,forms.py ..................................

```
from django import forms

PRODUCT_QUANTITY_CHOICES = [(i, str(i)) for i in range(25, 200+1, 25)]


class CartAddProductForm(forms.Form):
    quantity = forms.TypedChoiceField(
        choices=PRODUCT_QUANTITY_CHOICES,
        coerce=int)
    update = forms.BooleanField(required=False,
                                initial=False,
                                widget=forms.HiddenInput)
```

I don't know how fix this error,help please. ....................................

Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\my_projects\TeaYard\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py"
, line 55, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\my_projects\TeaYard\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", lin
e 197, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\my_projects\TeaYard\App\cart\views.py", line 30, in cart_detail
    for item in cart:
  File "C:\my_projects\TeaYard\App\cart\cart.py", line 28, in __iter__
    item['price'] = Decimal(item['price'])
decimal.InvalidOperation: [<class 'decimal.ConversionSyntax'>]
```

detail.html

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load static %}

{% block title %}
Корзина покупок
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
<h1>Корзина покупок</h1>
<table class="cart">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Картинка</th>
        <th>Товар</th>
        <th>Обновить кол-во</th>
        <th>Удалить</th>
        <th>Кол-во</th>
        <th>Цена за шт</th>
        <th>Общая стоимость</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    {% for item in cart %}
    {% with product=item.product %}
    <tr>
        <td>
            <a href="{{ product.get_absolute_url }}">
                <img src="{% if product.image %}{{ product.image.url }}{% else %}{% static 'PDF/no_image.png' %}{% endif %}">
            </a>
        </td>
        <td>{{ product.name }}</td>
        <td>
            <form action="{% url 'cart:cart_add' product.id %}" method="post">
                {{ item.update_quantity_form.quantity }}
                {{ item.update_quantity_form.update }}
                <input type="submit" value="Обновить">
                {% csrf_token %}
            </form>
        </td>
        <td><a href="{% url 'cart:cart_remove' product.id %}">Удалить</a></td>
        <td>
            {{ item.quantity }}
        </td>
        <td class="num">{{ item.price }}</td>
        <td class="num">{{ item.total_price }}</td>
    </tr>
    {% endwith %}
    {% endfor %}
    <tr class="total">
        <td>Всего</td>
        <td colspan="4"></td>
        <td class="num">{{ cart.get_total_price }}</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<p class="text-right">
    <a href="{% url 'home' %}" class="button light">В магазин</a>
    <a href="#" class="button">Оформить заказ</a>
</p>
{% endblock %}
```

```
C:\my_projects\TeaYard\App\cart\views.py, line 30, in cart_detail
    for item in cart: …
Local vars
C:\my_projects\TeaYard\App\cart\cart.py, line 35, in __iter__
                raise ValueError('price must be numeric value') …
Local vars
Variable    Value
cart    
{'1': {'price': '7 руб/кг',
       'product': <Products: Молочный улун>,
       'quantity': 325},
 '2': {'price': '7', 'quantity': 25}}
item    
{'price': '7 руб/кг', 'product': <Products: Молочный улун>, 'quantity': 325}
price   
'7 руб/кг'
product 
<Products: Молочный улун>
product_ids 
dict_keys(['1', '2'])
self    
<cart.cart.Cart object at 0x000001B47BA33FA0>
```

Comment: please provide full traceback of error

Comment: I added a full Traceback

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According traceback error happens in this line:

```
item['price'] = Decimal(item['price'])
```

It happens because `item['price']` is not numeric. For example this error may happens when value of `item['price']` is `''` or `abc`.

If you using Django Rest Framework then [serializers](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/validators/) is the best way to validate input data.

If you just want to simply avoid the error, The easiest way will be to check every time `item['price']`'s value:

```py
# convert to string first (to be able call isnumeric method)
price = str(item['price'])
# check if price string is numeric
if price.isnumeric()
  price = Decimal(price)
else:
  # handle bad value (raise error or whatever depending on your logic)
  raise ValueError('price must be numeric value')
```

Comment: Depending on actual situation, this approach might be better than mine.

Comment: I deleted my model and added a new one with a price of 7, but the data is not updated in Traceback. What should I do about it?

Comment: 1. If you updated code like I said, it is impossible that traceback is not changed. 2. I don't know what is your actual data in DB to do exact answer or any solution

Comment: I added Traceback,1 is not delete from cart.My project on russian language

Comment: I searched in the tables in the database but did not find anything.

Comment: Do you think that `7 руб/кг` is a numeric value? And what number should be ` руб/кг`?

Comment: `руб/кг` is 
rubles per kilogram

Comment: i want to delete 7 руб/кг and switch it on 7

Comment: can delete the table from the db and write it down correctly?

Answer (score 0):

You are passing incorrect value to `Decimal` function. If you give i.e. empty string (`""`) to that function, then you will get such error. You should check what value you are putting there.

You may try this in your `get_total_price` function of `Cart` model:

```
def get_total_price(self):
    price = item['price'] if item['price'] else 0
    return sum(Decimal(price) * item['quantity'] for item in self.cart.values())
```

If problem is the same with `'quantity'`, then resolve it in the same way.

Comment: But the cart now displays not the total cost, but a lot of prices per kg

Comment: I'm just answering to your specific problem and I believe I have solved it. I will not do whole review of your code.

Comment: @МатвейЗуев not a problem. Just tick my Answer as the correct one, so people know it's solved.